# Scaling Nodes in Pane within AnchorPane JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a 2 Nodes (One Text, the other a Circle) in a Pane, and that pane is within an AnchorPane. The reason why I did this is I wanted to use the automatic scaling property that is a result of resizing the AnchorPane to adjust the size of the Nodes (like stretching and shrinking).

I also have a test background to see if I could scale the background aswell.

My issue is that while the background scales when I resize the window, the Nodes do not.

Heres my code:

```
package javacode;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public boolean debug = false;

    Pane stack;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Check for updates
        /*
        System.out.println("Checking for update");
        boolean newUpdate = Updater.updateAvalible();
        System.out.println("New update avalible: " + newUpdate);
        if (newUpdate) {
            Updater.showUpdatePrompt();
        }
        */

        // Get the debug background image
        Image debugbackgroundimage = new Image(
                this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/debugbackground.jpg"));

        // Create a stack pane to add all the objects into
        stack = new Pane();

        // Setup the background
        stack.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(debugbackgroundimage, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, new BackgroundSize(
                        debugbackgroundimage.getWidth(), debugbackgroundimage.getHeight(), false, false, true, true))));

        // Set the preferred and minimum sizes for the stack
        stack.setPrefSize(debugbackgroundimage.getWidth(), debugbackgroundimage.getHeight());
        stack.setMinSize(16, 9);

        // We need an anchor pane go help automatically constrain the maximum and
        // minimum sizes of things
        AnchorPane anchor = new AnchorPane();
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(stack, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(stack, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(stack, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(stack, 0.0);


        // Add the stack to the anchor pane
        anchor.getChildren().addAll(stack);

        // Set the anchor background to a light gray, that way we can check for overlap
        anchor.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        // Set the scene for the visualizer, use the anchor pane defined above
        Scene mCatScene = new Scene(anchor);

        // Set the contents of the window to that of the scene
        stage.setScene(mCatScene);

        // Show the window (stage)
        stage.show();

        // Add a test node to check if it scales properly
        Text test = new Text(String.format("Test\nFoo bar"));

        test.setFont(new Font("Arial", 15));
        test.setWrappingWidth(500);
        test.setFill(Color.RED);
        test.setLayoutX(0);
        test.setLayoutY(50);

        Circle test2 = new Circle();
        test2.setLayoutX(50);
        test2.setLayoutY(120);
        test2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        test2.setRadius(10);


        stack.getChildren().add(0, test);
        stack.getChildren().add(1, test2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main This = new Main();

        // Check if debug mode is enabled (Basically check for console spam enabled)
        try {
            This.debug = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            This.debug = false;
        }

        launch(args);

    }
}
```

Here is the background image I used:
[image]

**Edit:** [Here](https://gfycat.com/OrdinaryPiercingAracari) is a gif of how the background reacts (which is ideal), vs how the Nodes react (not ideal)

Comment: I don't see a `Circle` in your code. Furthermore there doesn't seem to be an attempt to modify the size of the `Text`. Why do you expect it to change size?

Comment: @fabian yeah I forgot to add the circle, so that should be fixed now. In terms of modifying the size of the text, since its set within the Pane, and the pane itself is set to scale based on the AnchorPane, I assumed the text would scale aswell. Kind of like how the background scales with the AnchorPane, while being within the Pane.